# Completing 5 pages out of 10 random pages

Tags: javascript, html

How do I make sure that the user have already completed any 5 of this random 10 pages? For example, the 5th page will trigger an alert message that its done. Each page will have this set of code including the index/homepage.

```
var randomlinks = new Array()

            randomlinks[0] = "square1.html"
            randomlinks[1] = "square2.html"
            randomlinks[2] = "square3.html"
            randomlinks[3] = "square4.html"
            randomlinks[4] = "square5.html"
            randomlinks[5] = "square6.html"
            randomlinks[6] = "square7.html"
            randomlinks[7] = "square8.html"
            randomlinks[8] = "square9.html"
            randomlinks[9] = "squareLast.html"

            function randomlink() {
                window.location = randomlinks[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomlinks.length)]
            }

<button class="btnSquare" onclick="randomlink()"></button>
```

Comment: You probably want to have a look at [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) (and, notably, not [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), because you don't want this knowledge to persist outside of the current tab)

Comment: How do you identify users? Are these static pages? What does already completed mean, is there a something like a form submission? Please add some more context so that we can give you a good solution.